# Root routine in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a routine in C. Below is the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> //Este es el numpy de C (para seno y coseno, aqui)

int raices(float r,float discriminante,float a,float b,float c, float *r1, float *r2)
{
    discriminante=b*b-4*a*c;
    if(discriminante<0)
    {
        printf("Raices complejas\n");
    }
    else
    {
        r=sqrt(discriminante);
        *r1=(-b+r)/(2*a);
        *r2=(-b-r)/(2*a);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    float sina,cosa,a,b,g=9.8,v,h,t1,t2,d1,d2;
    printf("Ingrese la rapidez y el angulo (>0 y <90):");
    scanf("%f,%f",&v,&a);

    if(a<0 || a>90) 
    {
        printf("El angulo esta en un rango incorrecto\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Entre la altura final:");
    scanf("%f",&h);

    sina=sin(a);
    cosa=cos(a);
    t1=(1/2)*g;

    raices((1/2)*g,-v*sina,h,&t1,&t2);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with cc, i get these errors:

```
cc proyectil.c -o proyectil.out
proyectil.c: In function ‘main’:
proyectil.c:47:1: error: incompatible type for argument 4 of ‘raices’
raices((1/2)*g,-v*sina,h,&t1,&t2);

proyectil.c:6:5: note: expected ‘float’ but argument is of type ‘float *’
int raices(float r,float discriminante,float a,float b,float c, float *r1, float *r2)
    ^
proyectil.c:47:1: error: incompatible type for argument 5 of ‘raices’
raices((1/2)*g,-v*sina,h,&t1,&t2);
    ^
proyectil.c:6:5: note: expected ‘float’ but argument is of type ‘float *’
int raices(float r,float discriminante,float a,float b,float c, float *r1, float *r2)
    ^
proyectil.c:47:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘raices’
raices((1/2)*g,-v*sina,h,&t1,&t2);
   ^
proyectil.c:6:5: note: declared here
int raices(float r,float discriminante,float a,float b,float c, float *r1, float *r2)
    ^
```

Why does give me an error when I use `*`?
This is my first program in C so I don't really know why this is happening.

Comment: `raices` takes `7` arguments: `5` floats and `2` pointers. You called it with `3` floats and `2` pointers.

Comment: BTW `a` : It is necessary to convert degrees to radians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error is here:

```
int raices(float r,float discriminante,float a,float b,float c, float *r1, float *r2)
{
```

should be

```
void raices(float a,float b,float c, float *r1, float *r2)
{
    float r;
    float discriminante;
```

Comment: @VanesaPiedrahita it is english site, anyway - link with standard library to resolve it

Comment: Here. It is in english now:





      /tmp/cc48ZgES.o: In function `raices':
proyectil.c:(.text+0x66): reference to`sqrt' not defined
/tmp/cc48ZgES.o: In function  `main':
proyectil.c:(.text+0x168): reference to `sin' not defined
proyectil.c:(.text+0x185): reference to `cos' not defined
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @VanesaPiedrahita try add gcc option `-lm` for math lib.